# Callback in iOS application in offline mode

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Is there any way to get a call back in the iOS application in offline mode, even if the app is in the background or not running state?

What I meant was - Is there a way to perform a particular task in the app (e.g. scheduling local notifications) at scheduled time, if the app is in background or not running state?

Comment: Sort of. You can use a background push notification: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app

Comment: What is callback in offline mode?

Comment: What do you mean by “a callback”?

Comment: What I meant was - Is there a way to perform a particular task in the app (e.g. scheduling local notifications) at scheduled time, if the app is in background or not running state?

Comment: Add that to your question. The more information you provide in the question the easier it is to answer. If you have code that you have tried, add that too. If you have articles that you have read, add those too. If you have a specific example of what you want, add that too. 

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Firebase[1]

Once an app has connected to Firebase, the client will cache data locally and be able to access data where there is an outstanding "on" callback even after a network connection is lost.

You can enable disk persistence, your app writes the data locally to the device so your app can maintain state while offline, even if the user or operating system restarts the app.

You can enable disk persistence with just one line of code.
`Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true`

[1]https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/05/announcing-mobile-offline-support_93.html

Comment: It’s not even clear what the question is. How can you provide an answer?

Comment: I provided a solution with whatever i could make up from the question. Hoping it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Notification Request
init(identifier: String, content: UNNotificationContent, trigger: UNNotificationTrigger?)
Creates a notification request object that you use to schedule a notification.
[UNNotificationRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest)

Comment: It’s not even clear what the question is yet. How do you know this is a good answer?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).